# How to reset the scroll position of a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, scroll

I would like to completely reset the scroll position of a UITableView, so that every time I open it, it is displaying the top-most items. In other words, I would like to scroll the table view to the top every time it is opened.

I tried using the following piece of code, but it looks like I misunderstood the documentation:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

Is this the wrong approach here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

August got the UITableView-specific method. Another way to do it is:

```
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

This method is defined in UIScrollView, the parent class to UITableView. The above example tells it to scroll to the 1x1 box at 0,0 - the top left corner, in other words.

Comment: This is actually a pretty neat way of doing it because you don't need to worry about whether your table is empty or not. I had a nasty crash going to NSIndexPath (0,0) when there were no records to display.

Answer (score 6):

The method you're using scrolls to (as the method name implies) the nearest selected row. In many cases, this won't be the top row. Instead, you want to use either

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

or

```
selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:
```

where you use the index path of the row you want to scroll to. The second method actually selects a row, the first method simply scrolls to it.

Comment: These didn't work for me with iOS 4.0 during the start of an animation sequence.  I had to use scrollRectToVisible:animated:

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was this:

Swift 4

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect.zero, animated: false)
```